# Не могу вывести json из массива

Tags: javascript, json

Импортирую json с сайта следующим кодом:

```html
<script>
   $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=wpZks91nGR77-f95tWly-V3wSEpaQjKnCLemocHHIh3U-VbFPjcYQSz7DMx_Vs4iYcYZasFz-RBMJldLzkYgAeTI7HzzEii6m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnDiabh4KWLvMmWU4l8QvAK2AraxMHPbwtKkmeMatjpxaqsT37838HPPwKLk2MSnbxZcdv3aNHr6K&lib=MOqbr3VgUxAb_w_VN-nXYaq9CoS8oh-MD',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: displayAll
    });
</script>
```

После чего вывожу данны в консоль

```
 function displayAll(data){
    var res = data.user;

    console.log(res);
    }
```

Выводиться всё без проблем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но возникает проблема. Мне нужно пройтись циклом по всему списку, который возьмет значение Models и VIN после чего отобразит это в HTML.
Как это сделать, при попытке достать конкретное значение возникают ошибки.

Comment: {"user":[{"Models":"Megane","VIN":129391293},{"Models":"Duster","VIN":1231231},{"Models":"kangoo","VIN":123123},{"Models":"жигуль","VIN":"шащ2231"},{"Models":"цвйц","VIN":222},{"Models":213123,"VIN":312312}]}

Comment: У Вас опечатка в названии свойства `length`: `res.lenght`.

Comment: А ошибку не надо показывать? И как вы сделали обход, тоже не надо показывать? Странно.

Answer (score 0):

```
    res.forEach(element => {
        // любые действия над элементом
            element.Models 
            element.VIN
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = JSON.parse(yourJsonData);
for (var i = 0; i < res.user.length; i++) {
    var x = res.user[i];
    console.log(`${x.Models} : ${x.VIN}`);
}
```